# tensorflow to tflite - tflite_converted fails with "Axis 0 computes to size 0 for StridedSlice" when converting from .pb to .tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

I'm having an issue when converting from a saved .pb Tensorflow model to a .tflite Tensorflow Lite model using the Tensorflow (1.13.1) built-in tflite_convert tool, and I was wondering how I might go about solving this issue. When executing:

```
tflite_convert --output_file done --graph_def_file reshaped_t.pb --input_arrays the_input --output_arrays ctc/ExpandDims --allow_custom_ops
```

I'm met with the error:

```
F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:1499] Check failed: dim_size > 0 (0 vs. 0)Output size for an axis must be greater than 0. Axis 0 computes to size 0 for StridedSlice op with output "ctc/boolean_mask/strided_slice_1".
```

As a background, the model represented by the .pb file was originally a     Keras model with the structure as follows. I converted it to the .pb file with the tool found at `https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow`

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
the_input (InputLayer)          (1, 584, 13)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_1_conv (Conv1D)           (1, 287, 200)        28800       the_input[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_batch_norm (BatchNormaliza (1, 287, 200)        800         layer_1_conv[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
rnn_1 (GRU)                     (1, 287, 250)        338250      conv_batch_norm[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bt_rnn_1 (BatchNormalization)   (1, 287, 250)        1000        rnn_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
final_layer_of_rnn (GRU)        (1, 287, 250)        375750      bt_rnn_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bt_rnn_final (BatchNormalizatio (1, 287, 250)        1000        final_layer_of_rnn[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_13 (TimeDistri (1, 287, 29)         7279        bt_rnn_final[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_length (InputLayer)       (1, 1)               0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Activation)            (1, 287, 29)         0           time_distributed_13[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
the_labels (InputLayer)         (1, 29)              0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_24 (Lambda)              (1, 1)               0           input_length[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
label_length (InputLayer)       (1, 1)               0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
ctc (Lambda)                    (1, 1)               0           softmax[0][0]                    
                                                                 the_labels[0][0]                 
                                                                 lambda_24[0][0]                  
                                                                 label_length[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 752,879
Trainable params: 751,479
Non-trainable params: 1,400
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
>>>
```

Furthermore, here is the full log output from tflite_convert:

```
2019-06-19 14:49:24.878900: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/tflite_convert", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 442, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 438, in run_main
    _convert_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 191, in _convert_model
    output_data = converter.convert()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 455, in convert
    **converter_kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 442, in toco_convert_impl
    input_data.SerializeToString())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 205, in toco_convert_protos
    "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2019-06-19 14:49:25.969310: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977488: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977507: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977516: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977560: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977579: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977589: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977598: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977606: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977626: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977638: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977649: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977680: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977686: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977692: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977700: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977707: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977721: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977792: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977928: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977937: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977944: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977962: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977968: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.977989: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978827: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978838: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978847: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978853: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978887: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978904: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978912: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978920: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978929: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978947: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978957: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.978968: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979003: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979009: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979016: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979024: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979031: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979042: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979116: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979261: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979268: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979276: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979296: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979305: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979327: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979453: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979462: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979472: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979480: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979516: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979533: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979542: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979551: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979569: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979580: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979591: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979622: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979628: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979637: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979645: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979653: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979667: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979680: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979686: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979693: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979714: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979721: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979741: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979867: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979875: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979911: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979926: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979935: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979947: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979956: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979964: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979979: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.979994: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980024: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980030: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980036: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980045: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980066: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980097: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980111: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980118: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980125: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980144: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980151: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980172: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980305: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980350: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: ReverseV2
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980440: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980472: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: GatherNd
2019-06-19 14:49:25.980496: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: CTCLoss
2019-06-19 14:49:25.985282: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 350 operators, 629 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-06-19 14:49:25.989871: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 350 operators, 629 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-06-19 14:49:25.999322: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:1499] Check failed: dim_size > 0 (0 vs. 0)Output size for an axis must be greater than 0. Axis 0 computes to size 0 for StridedSlice op with output "ctc/boolean_mask/strided_slice_1".
```

I'll be happy to provide more background information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Currently TensorFlow Lite doesn't support TensorArray and Control Flow ops (e.g. Enter). The other errors are likely due to the unsupported ops.

It seems these ops comes from GRU. Could you try to pass `unroll=True` and see if it works? (It would work if your model handles static number of timesteps)

We're actively working on control flow, and hopefully can get something working soon (within ~1 month).